# How to drop final portion of multiple directory names?

Tags: directory, rename, mv

I have a number of directories with titles such as "20150512_101129_3016" and others with additional string following an additional underscore, such as "20150512_101129_3016_v1A" (it's not always v1A, could be v1, or V1a, etc). I would like to rename all directories such that the final string following the final underscore is removed. I'd prefer a solution that looks to remove all text following (and including) the final/3rd underscore since I am uncertain that all directory names will have the same number of characters in the text preceding the 3rd underscore.

Comment: [Parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion): `"${file%_*}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a simple shell loop:

```
for x in ./*_*_*_*; do mv -i "$x" "${x%_*}"; done
```

i.e. for every file whose name contains at least three underscores, rename the file, stripping off the part starting at the last underscore.

If there's a collision (e.g. both `20150512_101129_3016_v1A` and `20150512_101129_3016_v1B` exist), then the first file in lexicographic order is renamed to the desired target, and the second one is moved to a subdirectory, i.e. `20150512_101129_3016_v1B` gets moved to `20150512_101129_3016/20150512_101129_3016_v1B` after `20150512_101129_3016_v1A` has been renamed to `20150512_101129_3016`. To avoid this, add an extra check:

```
for x in ./*_*_*_*; do
  if [ -e "${x%_*}" ]; then
    echo "Not renaming $x because ${x%_*} already exists"
    continue
  fi
  mv "$x" "${x%_*}"
done
```

Alternatively, on Linux, pass the `-T` option to `mv` to make it do this check.

Answer (score -1):

if the original directory names are homogeneous, i.e. follows the format of XXXXX_XXXX_XXXX (then may be followed by another _ XXXX) this code segment below, should work:

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d | while read dir; do
newdir=$(echo ${dir} | cut -d_ -f1-3)
# duplicate directory name protection
if [ -d ${newdir} ]
then 
  newdir=${newdir}_
  echo "duplicate directory encountered. Appending _ to the new dir name"
fi

#did the dir name change ? If not, do nothing
if [ ${newdir} != ${dir} ]
then
  mv ${dir} ${newdir}
fi
done
```

it assumes you are in the directory which contains these subdirectories.

Comment: If this is a full tree then your `find` needs a `-depth` flag.  You should also test to see if `$dir` and `$newdir` are different.  Also test to see if `$newdir` already exists (eg if `a_b_c_v1` and `a_b_c_v1a` both exist they'll both try to become `a_b_c`).

Comment: I tried running the most recently edited suggested code in a .sh file and returned: `./suffix.sh: line 11: unexpected EOF while looking for matching }' ./suffix.sh: line 16: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Comment: I added a matching } to "newdir" on line 11, then returned: `find: warning: you have specified the -maxdepth option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-maxdepth affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.

duplicate directory encountered. Appending _ to the new dir name
mv: cannot move `./' to `./_': Device or resource busy`

Comment: I apologize a `}` sign went victim to an accidental backspace. Fixed it in the code. Please understand that, the improved code will add an underscore if you happen to have the same directory name with and without a 3rd _ character. I.e., if you have `20150512_101129_3016` and `20150512_101129_3016_V1a`, the latter will become `20150512_101129_3016_` to protect the original

Comment: Thank you. 2 more questions: 1) if I leave in the duplicate directory protection, it appears to also append "_" if there is no 3rd underscore, for example `20150512_101129_3016` becomes `20150512_101129_3016_`. Is there a way to prevent this from happening (as it is not a duplicate)? 2) if I remove the protection, it appears to run fine, but returns: `mv: `./' and `./.' are the same file`. Also, if I have a directory name without a 3rd underscore as per above, I get `mv: cannot move `./20150213_123852_3005' to a subdirectory of itself, `./20150213_123852_3005/20150213_123852_3005'`

Comment: You can remove the first `if` block if you are sure there will be no duplicate names during processing. 2nd `if` block is needed to prevent messages like `mv: ./' and ./.' are the same file`. It doesn't affect the effective outcome but throws out error messages like this, for directories which doesn't have the 3rd _ character in the name. But the second if block doesn't append the _ character by any means

Comment: [Always use double quotes around variable substitutions](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters). And don't use external tools for simple string operations that can be performed in the shell: it's hard to read, difficult to get right, and slow.